# In VEP annotation, how is the codon field interpreted?

Tags: sequence-annotation, vep

After annotating with [VEP](https://www.ensembl.org/vep) a VCF file, we obtain different fields. One of them is called `Codons` which represents the affected codon in the transcript of the gene. Below is a screenshot of `Insertions` from a sample:

[image]

Variants and INDELs affect genes differently depending on the transcript we are looking at. My question is, for some notations for Insertions like in the screenshot, how can we interpret these results? Let's take the example of `-/TC`. Is `TC` inserted at the end of the previous codon? or the next codon of the transcript?

Below are the different representations I have in mind where `|` is the position of the indel and `^` is the possible insertion scenario of `TC`.

```
                     Before insertion               after insertion
                           v|
first scenario          xxx xxx xxx                   xxx TCx xxx

second scenario         xxx xxx xxx                   xxx xxx TCx
                            |  ^
```

My gut is telling me that this depends more on the strand I am looking at. If the strand is `+`, it is likely to be the second scenario. Otherwise, it would be the first scenario. Am I thinking correctly? or does this notation have another meaning? Or maybe VEP is not able its position?

Thanks for the help.